# MapView and ViewPager : cannot use BitmapDescriptorFactory

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

So here is the deal : I'm using my MapView inside a ViewPager. Everything works fine with it, I've forwarded life cycle, etc...
But I'm not able to register and create a *BitmapDescriptor* because of BitmapDescriptorFactory throwing this :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'fr.defvs.gtfs.MainActivity$MapFrag'
```

This is my OnLongClick listener for my GoogleMap:

```
gMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng p1)
                {
                    lat.setText("Lat : " + String.valueOf(p1.latitude));
                    lon.setText("Lon : " + String.valueOf(p1.longitude));
                    selectedLatLng = p1;
                    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
                    addLocation(p1);
                    gpsButton.setChecked(false);
                    gpsMode = false;
                }

        });
```

And my addLocation method :

```
public void addLocation(LatLng latlng)
    {
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
            .flat(true).icon(new BitmapDescriptorFactory().fromResource(R.drawable.loc)));
    }
```

When executing the method, all I get is that nasty error...
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitmapDescriptorFactory has a private constructor, so you cannot make an instance of it.
Instead, all of it's methods are static so you don't need an instance.

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.loc)
```

See the [javadoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory) and [source code](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/openspace-android-sdk/blob/master/OSMapAndroid/src/main/java/uk/co/ordnancesurvey/android/maps/BitmapDescriptorFactory.java) pages.

I'm surprised you are not getting a compile time error for this. Are you not using an IDE with code analysis?

Comment: Hmmm... Yes. That looks weird. My IDE (AIDE for Android) is not saying anything... I'll try this and reply back.

Comment: So it definitely works. I'm stupid, and my IDE isn't here to correct me. Thanks a lot ;)